# Numbers too big for real value orbit simulation with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do some gravity simulations with real values but when I try to put the real values I'm getting a error that says "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long".

The values get just as big as the Sun Mass (1.98e+30 kg) - which is not that huge I believe (I hoped to do blackhole simulations with Python later this year). I tried to run the code both on Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 but sadly neither worked.

I've done some searching I found that most people get this error when they use a way to big xrange, which is not the case (the only xrange I use is at its maximum glory 0 to 1) and the program works just fine for little amounts of mass.

Is there something I can do? Or Python just can't handle the values (I find this unlikely)?

The whole Traceback is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Orbit2.py", line 166, in <module>
    main()
  File "Orbit2.py", line 155, in main
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 255), (int(WIDTHD2+zoom*WIDTHD2*(p._est._x-WIDTHD2)/WIDTHD2),int(HEIGHTD2+zoom*HEIGHTD2*(p._est._y-HEIGHTD2)/HEIGHTD2)),int(p._r*zoom), 0)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

And if it helps the whole code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import pygame
import math
from collections import defaultdict

# Tamanho da janela
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 600
WIDTHD2, HEIGHTD2 = WIDTH/2., HEIGHT/2.

# Número de planetas
PLANETAS=1

# Constante gravitacional
GRAVCONST = 6.67384e-11

# Densidade média dos planetas
DENSIDADE = 0.001

# Lista global de planetas
g_listaDePlanetas = []

class Estado:
    """ Classe que representa a posição e velocidade. """
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy):
        self._x, self._y, self._vx, self._vy = x, y, vx, vy

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'x:{x} y:{y} vx:{vx} vy:{vy}'.format(x=self._x, y=self._y, vx=self._vx, vy=self._vy)

class Derivada:
    """ Classe que representa a velocidade e aceleração. """
    def __init__(self, dx, dy, dvx, dvy):
        self._dx, self._dy, self._dvx, self._dvy = dx, dy, dvx, dvy 

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'dx:{dx} dy:{dy} dvx:{dvx} dvy:{dvy}'.format(dx=self._dx, dy=self._dy, dvx=self._dvx, dvy=self._dvy) 

class Planeta:
    """ Classe que representa um planeta. A parte "_est" significa "Estado", que carrega
    a posição e a velocidade do planeta. Enquanto "_m" representa a massa."""
    def __init__(self):
        self._est = Estado (150, 300, 0, 2)
        self._r = 1.5
        self._m = 5.97e24

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._est)

    def aceleracao(self, estado, un_t):
        """ Calcula a aceleração causada por outro planeta neste."""
        ax = 0.0
        ay = 0.0

        for p in g_listaDePlanetas:
            if p is self:
                continue
            dx = p._est._x - estado._x
            dy = p._est._y - estado._y
            dsq = dx*dx + dy*dy # distância quadratica
            dr = math.sqrt(dsq) # distância 
            forca = GRAVCONST*self._m*p._m/dsq

            ax += forca*dx/dr
            ay += forca*dy/dr
        return (ax, ay)

    def iniDerivada(self, estado, t):
        """ Parte do método de Runge-Kutta. """
        ax, ay = self.aceleracao(estado, t)
        return Derivada(estado._vx, estado._vy, ax, ay)

    def proxDerivada(self, iniEstado, derivada, t, dt):
        """ Parte do método de Runge-Kutta. """
        estado = Estado(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        estado._x = iniEstado._x + derivada._dx*dt
        estado._y = iniEstado._y + derivada._dy*dt
        estado._vx = iniEstado._vx + derivada._dvx*dt
        estado._vy = iniEstado._vy + derivada._dvy*dt
        ax, ay = self.aceleracao(estado, t+dt)
        return Derivada(estado._vx, estado._vy, ax, ay)

    def atualizarPlaneta(self, t, dt):
        """ Solução de Runge-Kutta de quarta ordem para pos/vel do planeta. """
        k1 = self.iniDerivada(self._est, t)
        k2 = self.proxDerivada(self._est, k1, t, dt*0.5)
        k3 = self.proxDerivada(self._est, k2, t, dt*0.5)
        k4 = self.proxDerivada(self._est, k3, t, dt)
        dxdt = 1.0/6.0 * (k1._dx + 2.0*(k2._dx + k3._dx) + k4._dx)
        dydt = 1.0/6.0 * (k1._dy + 2.0*(k2._dy + k3._dy) + k4._dy)
        dvxdt = 1.0/6.0 * (k1._dvx + 2.0*(k2._dvx + k3._dvx) + k4._dvx)
        dvydt = 1.0/6.0 * (k1._dvy + 2.0*(k2._dvy + k3._dvy) + k4._dvy)
        self._est._x += dxdt*dt
        self._est._y += dydt*dt
        self._est._vx += dvxdt*dt
        self._est._vy += dvydt*dt

    def massaFromRaio(self):
        """ A partir de _r define _m. """
        self._m = DENSIDADE*4.*math.pi*(self._r**3.)/3.

    def raioFromMassa(self):
        """ A partir de _m define _r. """
        self._r = (3.*self._m/(DENSIDADE*4.*math.pi))**(0.3333)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    win=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    keysPressed = defaultdict(bool)

    def ScanKeyboard():
        while True:
            evt = pygame.event.poll()
            if evt.type == pygame.NOEVENT:
                break
            elif evt.type in [pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP]:
                keysPressed[evt.key] = evt.type == pygame.KEYDOWN

    global g_listaDePlanetas, PLANETAS

    g_listaDePlanetas = []

    for i in xrange(0, PLANETAS):
        g_listaDePlanetas.append(Planeta())

    sol = Planeta()
    # Centraliza o sol na tela
    sol._est._x, sol._est._y = WIDTHD2, HEIGHTD2
    sol._est._vx = sol._est._vy = 0.0
    sol._m = 1.989e30 # Massa do sol
    sol._r = 3.5
    #sol.raioFromMassa()

    g_listaDePlanetas.append(sol)

    t, dt = 0.0, 1.0

    zoom = 1.0

    bClearScreen = True

    pygame.display.set_caption("Simulador de órbitas RK-4")

    while True:
        t += dt
        pygame.display.flip()
        if bClearScreen:  # Mostrar orbitas ou não
            win.fill((0, 0, 0))
        win.lock()
        for p in g_listaDePlanetas:
             pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 255), (int(WIDTHD2+zoom*WIDTHD2*(p._est._x-WIDTHD2)/WIDTHD2),int(HEIGHTD2+zoom*HEIGHTD2*(p._est._y-HEIGHTD2)/HEIGHTD2)),int(p._r*zoom), 0)
        win.unlock()
        ScanKeyboard()

        for p in g_listaDePlanetas:
            p.atualizarPlaneta(t, dt)

        if keysPressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to draw a circle that ridiculously huge?

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to understand the range of legal values for different types. The [largest int on most system is 9.2e18](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize). In most of your code you're using floating point numbers so this isn't a problem. However, you can see in the stack trace you posted that you got into trouble here:

```
pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 255), (int(WIDTHD2+zoom*WIDTHD2*(p._est._x-WIDTHD2)/WIDTHD2),int(HEIGHTD2+zoom*HEIGHTD2*(p._est._y-HEIGHTD2)/HEIGHTD2)),int(p._r*zoom), 0)
```

I didn't trace through all the code you posted to figure out what's being computed there or why, but suffice it to say, one of the two calls to `int()` in there is computing some very large value and trying to convert it to an int, and that won't work. I'm guessing that if you're drawing circles, this isn't a core part of your code (but again, I didn't trace the code or try to translate the comments into English) - I'm guessing that's just for visualization. If so, I suggest scaling these to something much, much smaller. It should still look the same on the screen if you scale everything but you'll be able to use integer math where you need it.